# Need help reading from a file and storing the contents into a 2d array

Tags: c

I'm trying to read a file and store the contents into a 2D Array to make a chess board. The file has the position of the pieces (board state). I think everythings fine but run I run it the build crashes. I'm not getting error messages or what line is causing it so i'm not sure what went wrong.

I tried using different scanf, and fgets methods, Finally I added a "show" method to see the board. I think this is crashing it.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)

{ 
FILE *in; //Create 2 file variables
char line[50];
int chessBoard[8][8];
int turn = 0;
in = fopen("board.csv","r");
int true = 1;
void show(int[][8]);
if(in == NULL )
{
    printf("The file specified couldn't be opened"
            "\nClose program and try again");
    true = 0;
    return 1;
}
else
{
  fscanf(in, "%d", &line);
      for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) 
      {
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
       fscanf(in, "%d", &chessBoard[i][j]);
    }
       }
}
show(chessBoard);
return 0;
}

void show(int chessBoard[8][8])
{
    for(int row = 0; row < 8; row++)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col< 8; col++)
        {
            printf("%d",chessBoard[row][col]);

            if(chessBoard[row][col] < 0)
            {
                printf("    ");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("    ");
            }
            if(col != 7)
            {
                printf("|");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
```

its supposed to print out the board state, but when I run it I get "run failed".

Comment: Your program does not compile. If you by "run failed" means "compile failed", then please post your error messages.

Comment: Tips: Turn on all compiler warnings. Solve all compiler warnings, ie. treat warnings as errors. Always handle I/O operations return value, ie. `fscanf` returns number of items successfully converted.

Comment: @HAL9000 I changed the "a+"  in the fopen statement, to just "r", now the error message is the file couldn't be opened?

Comment: The .csv is in the path (same folder as my main)

Comment: please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem.  Please post the input file so we can see how it should be read.  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note other compilers will use different options to produce the same thing

Comment: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
4 2 3 5 6 3 2 4
^^^ That's all thats in the file, as for minimal, that's all I have.

Comment: OT: regarding: `in = fopen("board.csv","r");`  when calling C library function, always check for an error condition and handle that error.  Example: `in = fopen("board.csv","r");`  if( !in ) { perror( "fopen to read board.csv failed" );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`  Where `exit()` and EXIT_FAILURE are from the header file: `stdlib.h`

Comment: The input file is (probably) not correct.  a 8x8 board has 64 positions so the input file contains 64 entries and it is assumed that each successive 8 entries represents the contents of 1 row

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding; 1) please consistently format the code. Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'. (suggest each indent level be 4 spaces)  Separate code blocks: `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` via a single blank line.  The compiler can work with 'scatter/gather' code but it is very difficult for us humans

Comment: in function: `main()`, this statement; `void show(int[][8]);`  results in a prototype for the `show()` function, However, when `main()` exits, the `show()` function no longer  has s prototype,  Suggest moving that prototype to before `main()`

Comment: @KappaTheRiotGod: `"board.csv"` must be in the *Current Directory*, which is not always the same directory as the executable.

Comment: OT: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers, like 8,  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understanding, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code

Comment: @user3629249: Everybody who has seen a chessboard knows what the number `8` stand for. No point in swapping it out with a longer and less descriptive label.

Comment: @HAL9000,  so, which `8`  is the row number and which `8` is the column number?   I'm also very familiar with how `8` would relate to a chess board.  However, all those `8`s leads to confusion that unnecessary.  The 'longer and less descriptive label' would be: `rowNum` and `colNum`  which are a LOT MORE descriptive than `8`

Comment: @user3629249 they're both 8.

Comment: regarding: `char line[50];` and `fscanf(in, "%d", &line);`    The `&line` parameter will be seen by the compiler as: `char *[50]` which is NOT what is needed.  Suggest `int line;`

Comment: @user3629249 I understand that, but it will be met with that else statement, and the output is still garbage. I also changed it to int line, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Without bothering to get your source to compile, there are at least two obvious errors:

```
fscanf(in, "%d", &line);
```

reads a decimal integer but has an incompatible argument to store it in.

```
show(chessBoard[8][8]);
```

is not the way to call `show()`. You give it only one integer as argument that is additionally taken out of bounds of `chessBoard`.

Comment: Hey I fixed the show method, and I used "%d" because the file only has numbers.

Comment: Now that you use @user3629249's proposed source code, do yo understand it? Use it to learn! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Hey so I think I fixed the errors the problem was how the input file was saved. Now, it just outputs garbage.  I also edited, my 'show' method.
Output:

[image]

Here's the file in a note document, (I added the '[]' because that's how it should look in the array).

```
   a   b  c  d  e  f  g  h
8  [-4][-2][-3][-6][-5][-3][-2][-4]
7  [-1][-1][-1][-1][-1][-1][-1][-1]

6  [0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]
5  [0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]
4  [0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]
3  [0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]

2  [1][1][1][1][1][1][1][1]
1  [4][2][3][5][6][3][2][4]
```

Heres my updated code with @ user3629249 help

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_ROWS  8
#define MAX_COLS  8

void show(int board[ MAX_ROWS ][ MAX_COLS ]);

int main(int argc, char** argv)

{ 
FILE *in; //Create 2 file variables
int line[50];
 int chessBoard[ MAX_ROWS ][ MAX_COLS ];
int turn = 0;
in = fopen("board.csv","r");
int true = 1;


if(in == NULL )
{
    printf("The file specified couldn't be opened"
            "\nClose program and try again");
    true = 0;
    return 1;
}
else
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ROWS; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < MAX_COLS; j++)
        {
            fscanf(in, "%d", &chessBoard[i][j]);
        }
    }

}
show(chessBoard);
return 0;
}

void show(int chessBoard[][8])
{
    for(int row = 0; row < MAX_ROWS; row++)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col< MAX_COLS; col++)
        {
            printf("|");
            if(chessBoard[row][col] < 0)
            {
                printf("    ");
            }

            else
            {
                printf("%07d",chessBoard[row][col]);
            }
        }
        printf("|\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: what about row 6?

Comment: in C, indexing starts at 0 and continues to (number of elements in array -1)

Comment: Haha, that's just me forgetting row 6 sorry. I updated the answer to include it.

Comment: if your numbering the rows, starting with the last row, then you will need to modify the code in the `show()` function to start at the last row (number 7) and loop toward row (number 0)  Other wise the output will not match your posted 'notepad' layout

Comment: Maybe adding the notepad document was confusing. Heres the direct .csv opened in notepad++ 
-4,-2,-3,-6,-5,-3,-2,-4
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
4,2,3,5,6,3,2,4
no numbering or letters just literal values.

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. incorporates the comments to the question
2. cleanly compiles
3. performs the desired functionality
4. properly cleans up after it self
5. uses appropriate vertical spacing
6. uses consistent indenting style
7. does not use 'magic' numbers

caveat:  The proposed code only outputs the 'positive' position values and prints spaces for the 'negative' position values

and now, the proposed code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define MAX_ROWS  8
#define MAX_COLS  8

void show(int board[ MAX_ROWS ][ MAX_COLS ]);


int main( void )
{  
    int chessBoard[ MAX_ROWS ][ MAX_COLS ];

    FILE *in = fopen("board.csv","r");
    if( !in )
    {
        perror( "fopen to read board.csv failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ROWS; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < MAX_COLS; j++)
        {
            fscanf(in, "%d", &chessBoard[i][j]);
        }
    }

    show(chessBoard);
    fclose( in );
    return 0;
}


void show(int chessBoard[ MAX_ROWS ][ MAX_COLS ])
{
    for(int row = 0; row < MAX_ROWS; row++)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col < MAX_COLS; col++)
        {
            printf("|");
            if(chessBoard[row][col] < 0)
            {
                printf("    ");
            }

            else
            {
                printf("%4d",chessBoard[row][col]); //edited
            }
        }
        printf("|\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks alot really appreciate it, I updated my show method to your show method(Im going to post another answer because I'm still receiving errors). I also included your definitions and how I input my file into the array. I'm still getting garbage output

Comment: then modify the `%07d` to `%4d'  so it does not output the leading zeros and shortens the displayed field to match the blank fields.  I'll edit my answer

Comment: Hey again, thanks alot, you have saved me alot of frustration (and im not even halfway done still need to do moves and captures) anyways, im a lot closer so thank you, but the output is still slightly off. output>>
http://prntscr.com/o2diwp